# JSP form not submitting on button click

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp

Hello I am new to JSP Programming. I have been given a task where I create a personal loan application form. When a user enters all the details in the form and hits submit the form gets stored in the database. I have created the form and all the required JSP pages and connectivity statements. My problem is that when I give values and click on submit nothing happens. It is staying in the same page. I don't know where the problem is. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
Application form.jsp
    <%@ page language="java" import="java.util.Random"%>
    <%!
    public int generateRandomNumber(int start, int end ){
        Random random = new Random();
        long fraction = (long) ((end - start + 1 ) * random.nextDouble());
        return ((int)(fraction + start));
    }
    %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeContents(){

    var dropDown = document.getElementById("employmenttype");
    var showDetails = document.getElementById("salariedType");
    showDetails.style.display = dropDown.value == "salaried" ? "block" :     "none";

    var elements = document.getElementById("employmenttype");
    var businessDetails = document.getElementById("selfEmployedType");
    businessDetails.style.display = elements.value == "self_employed_business" ? "block" : "none";  

    }  
    </script>
    <title>Bank</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Welcome to Bank</h1>
            <p></p>

        </div>




            <form action="personalloanhandler.jsp" method="POST">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            Your Application ID: <input type="text" name="app_id" value="<%=generateRandomNumber(10000,99999)%>" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>

                <div class="col-md-5">  

                            Full Name:*
                             <input class="form-control" name="fullname" type="text" />
                             <br><br>
                            Mobile No.:*
                            <input name="mobilenumber" class="form-control" type="text" pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" title="ex:9870367035"required />
                            <br><br>
                            Email_ID:*<input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" title="ex:hari21@gmail.com" required />
                            <br><br>
                            Pancard NO:*<input name="pan" class="form-control" type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{5}\d{4}[A-Za-z]{1}" title="ex:AIAPY3476G" required />
                            <br><br>
                            Gender: <input class="form-control"
                              name="gender" type="radio">Male
                            <input class="form-control"name="gender" type="radio">Female
                            <br><br>    
                            Date OF Birth (DD/MM/YYYY):<input class="form-control" type="date" name="seldob" required>
                            <br><br>
                            Age*<input class="form-control"name="age" type="text" required />
                            <br><br>
                            Address* <textarea class="form-control" name="address" rows="2" cols="20"  required>
                            </textarea>
                            <br><br>
                            City*<input class="form-control" name="city" id="focusedInput" type="text"  required />
                            <br><br>
                            State* 
                            <select name="state" onchange ="showText(this.value)">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value='Andamans and Nicobar' >Andamans and Nicobar</option><option value='Andhra Pradesh' >Andhra Pradesh</option><option value='Arunachal Pradesh' >Arunachal Pradesh</option><option value='Assam' >Assam</option><option value='Bihar' >Bihar</option><option value='Chandigarh (UT)' >Chandigarh (UT)</option><option value='Chhattisgarh' >Chhattisgarh</option><option value='Dadra and Nagar Haveli' >Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option><option value='Daman Dui' >Daman Dui</option><option value='Delhi' >Delhi</option><option value='Goa' >Goa</option><option value='Gujarat' >Gujarat</option><option value='Habra' >Habra</option><option value='Haryana' >Haryana</option><option value='Himachal Pradesh' >Himachal Pradesh</option><option value='Jammu and Kashmir' >Jammu and Kashmir</option><option value='Jharkhand' >Jharkhand</option><option value='Karnataka' >Karnataka</option><option value='Kerala' >Kerala</option><option value='Madhya Pradesh' >Madhya Pradesh</option><option value='Maharashtra' >Maharashtra</option><option value='Manipur' >Manipur</option><option value='Meghalaya' >Meghalaya</option><option value='Mizoram' >Mizoram</option><option value='Nagaland' >Nagaland</option><option value='Odisha' >Odisha</option><option value='Puducherry' >Puducherry</option><option value='Punjab' >Punjab</option><option value='Rajasthan' >Rajasthan</option><option value='Sikkim' >Sikkim</option><option value='Tamil Nadu' >Tamil Nadu</option><option value='Telangana' >Telangana</option><option value='Tripura' >Tripura</option><option value='Uae' >Uae</option><option value='Uttar Pradesh' >Uttar Pradesh</option><option value='Uttarakhand' >Uttarakhand</option><option value='West Bengal' >West Bengal</option>
                            </select>
                            Pincode* <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text"  required />
                            <br><br>
                            Type of employment* 
                            <select name="employmenttype" id="employmenttype"
                            class="employer-info" onchange="changeContents()">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="salaried" id="salaried" >Salaried</option>
                            <option value="self_employed_business" id="self_employed_business">Self Employed business</option>                                  
                            </select><br/></div>
                            <div id="salariedType"  class="employer-info" style="display:none;">
                            <br/>Retirement age:*<input class="employer-info" name="retirementage"
                            id="focusedInput" type="text"  required />
                            <br><br>
                            Date of joining:*<input class="employer-info" name="doj"
                            id="focusedInput" type="text" required />
                            <br><br>
                            Experience:<select class="form-control" name="workexperience">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>
                        <option value="0"> &lt;1 </option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">&gt;10</option>                      
                        </select>
                        <br><br>
                            </div>
                            <br><br>
                            <div id = "self_employed_business" style="display:none">
                            TIN no:*<input class="form-control" name="tin" id="focusedInput" type="text"  required /><br/>
                            <br><br>
                            Net profit (annually):*<input class="form-control" name="profit" id="focusedInput" type="text"  required /><br/><br/>
                            </div>
                        <div class="form-control" id="salariedType1"  style="display:none;">
                            <br/>Employer name:*
                            <select name="employer_name" id="focusedInput"
                            class="employer-info">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="IBM" >IBM</option>
                            <option value="Fujitsu" >Fujitsu</option>
                            <option value="CSC" >CSC</option>
                            <option value="Accenture" >Accenture</option>
                            <option value="Northrop Grumman" >Northrop Grumman</option>
                            <option value="Hitachi" >Hitachi</option>
                            <option value="Capgemini" >Capgemini</option>
                            <option value="NTT Data Corporation" >NTT Data Corporation</option>
                            <option value="NEC" >NEC</option>
                            <option value="Ericsson" >Ericsson</option>
                            <option value="BT Global Services" >BT Global Services</option>
                            <option value="Atos Origin" >Atos Origin</option>
                            <option value="T-Systems" >T-Systems</option>
                            <option value="Siemens" >Siemens</option>
                            <option value="Lockheed Martin" >Lockheed Martin</option>
                            <option value="Nokia Siemens Networks" >Nokia Siemens Networks</option>
                            <option value="SAIC" >SAIC</option>
                            <option value="Microsoft" >Microsoft</option>
                            <option value="ACS" >ACS</option>
                            <option value="Huawei" >Huawei</option>
                            <option value="Dell" >Dell</option>
                            <option value="Logica" >Logica</option>
                            <option value="General Dynamics" >General Dynamics</option>
                            <option value="Alcatel-Lucent" >Alcatel-Lucent</option>             
                                    <option value="Self Employed Professional">Self Employed
                                        Professional</option> 

                        </select><br/><br/>

                    </div>
                        Monthly Income<input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" name="monthly_income"  required />      
                        <br><br>
                        Reason for loan:*
                        <select  class="form-control" name="reason_for_loan">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>
                        <option value="newcar">Car</option>
                        <option value="marriage">Marriage</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                        <br><br>
                        Total years of work experience:*
                        <select class="form-control" name="experience">
                        <option value="select">Select</option>
                        <option value="0"> &lt;1 </option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">&gt;10</option>                      
                        </select>
                        <br><br>
                        Tenure:*<input name="loan_tenure" type="text" class="form-control"required />
                        <br><br>    
                        Loan Amount:*<input type="text" name="loan_amt" class="form-control" required />    
                        <br/><br/>
                        ROI:10.5<input name="emi" type="text" value=10.5 class="form-control" disabled> 
                        <br><br>
                        EMI:* <input name="emi" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                        <br><br>        
                        Guarantor Name:*<input name="guarantorname" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                        <br><br>
                        Guarantor's Annual income(Rs):*<input name="guarantor_address" class="form-control" type="text"required />
                        <br><br>
                        Guarantor's Phone number:*<input name="guarantor_contact" class="form-control" type="text"required />
                        <br><br>
                        Existing customer:* <input class="form-control" name="cust_gender" type="radio" value="yes">Yes
                            <input class="form-control" name="cust_gender" type="radio">No<br/>
                        <br><br>
                        <input class="form-control" type="checkbox"required /> I agree with terms & conditions:*
                        <br><br>    
                        Savings account number:*<input class="form-control" name="acc_no" type="text"required >
                        <br><br>

                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="personalloanhandler" />


    </div>
    </form>
    </div>   


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#divLoanApplicationForm").hide();
             $("#salariedType").hide();
             $("#selfEmployedType").hide();

        });


        $("#salaried").click(function(e){
             $("#divLoanApplicationForm").hide();
             $("#salariedType").show();
             $("#selfEmployedType").hide(); 

        });

        $("#self_employed_business").click(function(e){
             $("#divLoanApplicationForm").show();
             $("#salariedType").hide();
             $("#selfEmployedType").show(); 

        });
        /*$("#employmenttype").ready(function(e) {

            var value=$("#employmenttype").val();

             $("#divLoanApplicationForm").show();
            if(value=="SALARIED")
            {
            $("#selfEmployedType").hide();
             $("#salariedType").show();

            }
            if(value=="SELF_EMPLOYED_BUSINESS")
            {
             $("#selfEmployedType").show();
             $("#salariedType").hide();
            }

        });*/



        </script>

        </body>
        </html>

The Jsp Page(personalloanhandler.jsp):

    <%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*"%>
    <%
    String appid = request.getParameter("app_id");
    String mobileNumber = request.getParameter("mobilenumber");
    String emailId = request.getParameter("email");
    String pancardNumber = request.getParameter("pan");
    String applicantGender = request.getParameter("gender");
    String dateofBirth = request.getParameter("seldob");
    String applicantAddress = request.getParameter("address");
    String cityofResidence = request.getParameter("city");
    String stateofResidence = request.getParameter("state");
    String typeofEmployment = request.getParameter("employmenttype");
    String retirementAge = request.getParameter("retirementage");
    int retiringAge = Integer.parseInt(retirementAge);
    String dateofJoining = request.getParameter("doj");
    String workExperience = request.getParameter("workexperience");
    int experienceinWork = Integer.parseInt(workExperience);
    String tinNo = request.getParameter("tin");
    int tin = Integer.parseInt(tinNo);
    String netProfit = request.getParameter("profit");
    int profit = Integer.parseInt(netProfit);
    String employeeName = request.getParameter("employer_name");
    String monthlyIncome = request.getParameter("monthly_income");
    int monthIncome = Integer.parseInt(monthlyIncome);
    String reasonforLoan = request.getParameter("reason_for_loan");
    String totalworkExpreience = request.getParameter("experience");
    int workExperienceTotal = Integer.parseInt(totalworkExpreience);
    String loanTenure = request.getParameter("loan_tenure");
    int tenure = Integer.parseInt(loanTenure);
    String loanAmount = request.getParameter("loan_amt");
    int loanAmt = Integer.parseInt(loanAmount);
    String guarantorName = request.getParameter("guarantorname");
    String guarantorAddress = request.getParameter("guarantor_address");
    String guarantorContact = request.getParameter("guarantor_contact");
    int guarantorNo = Integer.parseInt(guarantorContact);
    String emiAmount = request.getParameter("emi");
    int emiAmt = Integer.parseInt(emiAmount);
    String savingsaccntNumber = request.getParameter("acc_no");
    int accNo = Integer.parseInt(savingsaccntNumber);
    String applicantName = request.getParameter("fullname");

    try{

          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","hr","themoonwalker");
          PreparedStatement prepare = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO BOI_Personal_loan_app-form values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
             prepare.setString(1,appid);
             prepare.setString(2,mobileNumber);
             prepare.setString(3,emailId );
             prepare.setString(4,pancardNumber );
             prepare.setString(5,applicantGender);
             prepare.setString(6,dateofBirth );
             prepare.setString(7,applicantAddress);
             prepare.setString(8,cityofResidence);
             prepare.setString(9,stateofResidence);
             prepare.setString(10,typeofEmployment);
             prepare.setInt(11,retiringAge);
             prepare.setString(12,dateofJoining);
             prepare.setInt(13,experienceinWork);
             prepare.setInt(14,tin);
             prepare.setInt(15,profit);
             prepare.setString(16,employeeName);
             prepare.setInt(17,monthIncome);
             prepare.setString(18,reasonforLoan);
             prepare.setInt(19,workExperienceTotal);
             prepare.setInt(20,tenure);
             prepare.setInt(21,loanAmt);
             prepare.setString(22,guarantorName);
             prepare.setString(23,guarantorAddress );
             prepare.setInt(24,guarantorNo );
             prepare.setInt(25,emiAmt );
             prepare.setInt(26,accNo);
             prepare.setString(27,applicantName );
             int i = prepare.executeUpdate();
                if (i > 0){
                    out.println("Success");
                }
    }catch(Exception e){
          System.out.println("Sorry couldn't process the request. Please try again");
    }

    out.close();
    %>
```

I have included the necessary jar files and everything in the project. Please help

Answer (score 1):

tin and profit inputs are required but not visible, so you can't submit the form

```
        <div id = "self_employed_business" style="display:none">
            TIN no:*<input class="form-control" name="tin" id="focusedInput" type="text"  required /><br/>
            <br><br>
            Net profit (annually):*<input class="form-control" name="profit" id="focusedInput" type="text"  required /><br/><br/>
        </div>
```

Comment: Okay I got that. Thanks